# cancel a sudo askpass request

Tags: bash, sudo, kdialog

I'm trying to use kdialog with sudo in a bash script, by exporting SUDO_ASKPASS to a script that has the line

```
kdialog --password "enter password: "
```

and using sudo -A.  This works well, **except** that if I click **cancel** in the dialogue, sudo ignores that, and retries the password entry after a delay.  The one-line script exits with kdialog's exit status, which is non-zero if cancel is clicked.

Is there any way to persuade sudo to give up, as one can with the text interface by typing control-C?

Edit - eventually I worked out what was going on.  If you click cancel, kdialog outputs a newline.  Sudo --askpass interprets this as a blank password, and starts its wrong password processing.  The askpass script must not emit that newline if cancel is clicked.  A way to do this is

```
pe=$(kdialog --password 'enter password: ') && echo "$pe"
```

Comment: another option would be to use `$SUDO_ASKPASS=$(which ksshaskpass)`

Comment: @NoortheenRaja, you can't have `$` on the left hand side of an assignment in shell.

Comment: yes my bad, juggling between bash and xonsh `SUDO_ASKPASS=$(which ksshaskpass)`

Answer (score 0):

For this, after few tries, I now use the following workaround for the `SUDO_ASKPASS` script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

kdialog --password 'Enter password: ' || kill -9 "${PPID}"
```

If the user chooses to cancel, then the calling process (the sudo command) is killed.

To mitigate the risk of killing your own process by error if you call the script directly from the command line, you can harden it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

kdialog --password 'Enter password: ' || [ ! -z ${DIE_ON_CANCEL+x} ] && kill -9 "${PPID}"
```

Then, if you want to kill the process on cancel, the `DIE_ON_CANCEL` variable must be defined explicitly like this:

```sh
SUDO_ASKPASS='<your script>' DIE_ON_CANCEL=true sudo --askpass <your command here>
```

I don't like to use `kill`, but I don't see any other solution. Somebody has a better idea?